# eth_getLogs request works for Eth Mainnet, but not polygon mumbai. Error -32602, missing value for required argument 0

Tags: json-rpc, polygon, logs

I'm trying to get do a eth_getLogs call, but I'm having problems getting a response with the Polygon chains. Strangely, I make the request with Polygon Mainnet data that I know exists, but when I do I get the following error

> {"code":-32602,"message":"missing value for required argument 0"}

but when I make the same request on the Eth mainnet, it works.

My failing request is

```
curl https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/myKey \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","parameters":[{"fromBlock":"29597527","toBlock":"29597529","topics":["0x788f224aea8528cb3199d1615151d4b851c884ad39e72c306356520ec6d2cf95"]}],"id":1}'
```

However this request works.

```
curl https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/myKey \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","parameters":[{"fromBlock":"29597527","toBlock":"29597529","topics":["0x788f224aea8528cb3199d1615151d4b851c884ad39e72c306356520ec6d2cf95"]}],"id":1}'
```

Could anyone help me to understand this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by reading the docs more closely.

> fromBlock [optional, default is "latest"] - hexadecimal block number, or the string "latest", "earliest" or "pending"

> toBlock [optional, default is "latest"] - hexadecimal block number, or the string "latest", "earliest" or "pending"

My block numbers needed to be hexademicals, starting with 0x

Strange how the request worked for Eth

Comment: This behaviour actually also seems to be the case for all non-mainnet-related chains. I.e. Rinkeby, and Kovan, for example behave the same as mainnet whereas Optimism and Arbitrum behave like Polygon. Still have no idea why.